# Wrapping markdownToHTML input in an HTML container?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown

Does anyone know if it is possible have the output of `knit2html` (i.e. `markdownToHTML`) wrapped in an HTML container?

Currently, everything gets dumped into `<body>`, which does not provide a lot of flexibility for controlling the layout.

For example, what I would like to from something like:

**example.md**

```
<div id='main'>
Markdown
========
some text, etc. here...
</div>
```

To:

**example.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body>
<div id='main'>
(HTML VERSION OF MARKDOWN
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I leave out the div container, the markdown is translated perfectly and placed at the top-level of `<body>`. What I would like to do is simply place in in a child container of body, thus allowing me to have finer control over the formatting of the contents.

Any ideas?

Comment: Most implementations of `markdown` will interpret anything between `div` tags as HTML and leave the content in-between untouched. `pandoc` is the only markdown transformer that I am aware of that might be the exception.

Answer (score 1):

In your call to `markdownToHTML` set an option called `fragment_only`:

```
markdownToHTML(..., options=c('fragment_only')
```

That'll skip putting it in a body, I believe, and then you should be able to do with it as you will.

You should be able to specify that in a call to `knit2html` as well, as part of the `...` argument.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately that doesn't do it though (posted example above for better formatting...)

Comment: @Keith Perhaps you should supply a more complete example of the source that you want to render, because my answer here is suggesting that you could run `markdownToHTML` with `fragment_only` to build several pieces which you could then incorporate into a larger document. If you know that `markdownToHTML` ignores content inside `<div>`, I'm not sure why you would expect specifying `fragment_only` to change that behavior (as you seem to in your second example).

Comment: Sorry If I didn't explain things well. My basic goal is to do exactly what `markdownToHTML()` currently does, but to be able to provide some control regarding where the resulting HTML is embedded. I'll put another example above.

Comment: 1. rename `example.html` to `example.Rhtml`; 2. use `<!--rinline markdown::markdownToHTML(text = readLines('example.md'), fragment_only = TRUE) -->` in `example.Rhtml`, and `knit()` it; 3. ??... 4. profit!